# How to edit template header

Tags: magento2, template

I want to change header in template.

- Hide `cart` , `Login`, `wishlist` etc.

from:

> https://zabezcen.pl/

to:

> http://zabezcen.pl/strona.png

Anyone help me how can I do ?

@Update

Thank you Guys, I did it this way - working perfect.

Last question,
Anyone help now, how to move block top search to top?

Comment: Hello :) I would strongly recommend to ask a new question instead of editing the original question with a new one ;) Check out my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove your `header-top`, `header-middle` then, you edit `header-bottom` to add your logo in the left side according to your example.

To remove the `header-top` and `header-middle`, you have to find the blocks or containers name in your xml, then you remove them also via xml.

Try:

> app/design/frontend/Sm/market/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

before `</body>` :

```
<referenceBlock name="header-top" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="header-middle" remove="true"/>
```

Or

```
<referenceContainer name="header-top" remove="true"/>
<referenceContainer name="header-middle" remove="true"/>
```

If it doesn't work, find the exact name block/container.

Don't forget to clean the cache.

Good luck.

Comment: I updated my topic

Comment: @Sylvester please don't ask multiple questions in the same topic, accept the answer that helped you then, then about the your new question if you don't find an answer, you can open a new topic. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Go to app->design->frontend->YOUR_THEME->layout->default.xml

add this under body tag

```
<referenceBlock name="logo" remove="true">
<referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />  
<referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true" />     
<referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />          
<referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />
```

Comment: I updated my topic

Answer (score 1):

To move block to desired position you can use `move` node. You have to find out the name of the blocks and you can follow this example:

```
<move element="name.of.an.element" destination="name.of.destination.element" as="new_alias" after="name.of.element.after" before="name.of.element.before"/>
```